# 5 LEDs work in parallel but not in series. Why exactly?

Tags: led, current, parallel, series

I've been learning electronics very thoroughly for the past couple of weeks. I'm running experiments on LED circuits at the moment and there is one thing that is completely beyond my comprehension.

I've built two circuits with 5 green LEDs each. Details aren't that important because **my issue touches on a general rule rather than specific settings.**

[image: 5 LEDs in series]

As you can see those LEDs don't work - obviously, simple maths can explain why. This is all clear to me. I didn't even bother with connecting a resistor - differences with or without are miniscule.

**BUT!**

When I connect those same LEDs in parallel, they light up bright and shiny.

[image: 5 LEDs in parallel with resistors.]

Obviously, maths can explain it too. They all take up to 70mA - which is understandable, no problem here.

**What I'm not able to understand however, is:** and here is 4 variations of basically the same question/concept:

1. What exactly prevents LEDs in series to take the necessary current from the battery?
2. Why are those in parallel able to reach the necessary current?
3. LEDs in parallel have unlimited access to the battery's potential, it seems. LEDs in series don't.
4. How to visualize that?

I've been really struggling, looking for answers in a few places, every time hitting a wall. I'm not even able to phrase this properly, therefore looking for answers is almost impossible.

Comment: Consider the Green Led's like tiny 3V batteries . It takes 3 to  make 9V and using them in parallel wont do it.  Then you can pair another 3 LED's to the battery as long as it stays at 9.25. When it drops below 9V they will get dim'. But don't connect 2 LEDs to 9V unless you use a larger resistor

Comment: _"... with 5 green LEDs each. Details aren't that important ..."_ - Details aren't important huh? For fun, try 5 **red** LEDs in the same configuration ;)

Comment: You might want to explain why the volt drop across D2 is only 1.24 volts and, given that the 5 LEDs are supposedly identical, the total volt drop would be 6.2 volts and this is contradictory to your supply of 9.28 volts. The devil's in the detail when it comes to engineering so, when detail appears contradictory, a rat is smelled somewhere. You need to fix this anomaly.

Comment: Your first schematic is not possible. If you have 1.24V across one of the LEDs then there must be some current flowing. Details **are** that important.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson it is possible AND it certainly is not relevant to the question I posed. I'm measuring it right now as I write this comment.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, and I'm measuring it again right at this moment.
It's clear to me, that it's the battery's internal resistance to blame for it - although I may be wrong. Anyhow, this issue is not related to my question. LEDs don't work in series, but they work in parallel - that's it, that's the question.

Comment: Of course LEDs work in series - they are usually preferred to be wired in series.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Yes, beautiful! I love this analogy.
Now, when we use it in case of a parallel circuit, suddenly it doesn't matter anymore - I can run 5 LEDs. Why?

Comment: @marcelm Yes, I know that. The issue isn't why 5 green LEDs won't work in series. It's about why they WILL work in parallel.

Comment: @Andyaka are you referring to my original question and example or are we talking general theory? Because in my example they don't work and I know why - maths. In the original question I'm asking why 5 LEDs in a parallel circuit are able to work while they can't in series. THAT difference is the crux of the issue.

Comment: @EagleEye123 Then your measurements are incorrect. The current may be too small for your meter to measure, or you may be measuring incorrectly, but if there is truly zero current flowing through a diode then it can not possibly have a positive forward voltage. It is not possible.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson how is this relevant to the original question? Yeah, maybe it's a couple of micro amps, whatever.

Comment: @EagleEye123 If you ask people to take the time to help you it is just common courtesy to give them correct and complete information.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Dude, you haven't answered: how is this relevant to my original question? All relevant numbers and structure is good enough to answer it. You're off topic, go away. Take your downvote with you.

Comment: You've indicated that you want to learn electricity thoroughly, so reading what I do here about what you're misunderstanding, you should review Voltage, Current, Resistance, Power, Ideal and real components, Ohm's Law, Watt's Law, Series/Parallel resistance, Kirchoff's Laws.  Next you'd normally learn capacitance and inductance, but to understand what's going on with what you're asking it would be adequate to read about diodes.  The few basic formulas listed above become necessary in almost all EE projects and you can learn them easily with grade 9 or 10 math.

Comment: @KH WOW I would have never guessed that in order to learn electricity I have to read about all this things! I thought it's just about connecting cables.

Comment: That list is just a very barebones basic to get you started with beginner level projects so you can use basic components without frying them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A green LED needs about 2 volts over it to be able to pass enough current to light it up.

Add that up and 5 green LEDs need about 10 volts to light up, so a battery providing less than that is not enough to light up the LEDs.

Comment: Certainly, yes. I get it up to that point. All good.
However, how come the parallel version is able to extract the necessary current. LEDs don't add up in it?

Comment: The Green LEDs wont be full brightness at 9.25V/3 to match but the current wont be excessive without a resistor but will be dim if the battery goes << 9V otherwise if its a DC supply, no worries. otherwise 2 LEDs + R=3V/20mA = 150 Ohms

Comment: In the parallel version, 9V is more than enough to light up 2V LED, there's excess of 7V dropped in the resistor.

Comment: WOW! So this was the solution all along! The parallel circuit offers voltage that is dropped on resistors, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, lighting up 5 LEDs in series requires voltage that is higher than 5 times the forward voltage drop of single LED. Lighting up 5 LEDs in parallel requires only higher voltage than voltage drop of single LED. So you need something between 10 and 15 volts to light your green LEDs in series, while 4 to 5 volts is fine for lighting up single LED or many LEDs in parallel.

Comment: Sir, if there was a prize for solving this problem you would be a winner. I can't thank you enough. Man, I was really struggling with it. Thank you. I can promise you I'll help somebody else with equal patience.

Answer (score 1):

Your LEDs don't work in series because you don't have enough voltage. In your parallel circuit, you have 7.5 volts (according to your meter) supplying a total of 70 ma to 5 LEDs.  Assuming equal current division, that is 14 ma per LED. That means each 330 ohm resistor is dropping 4.62 volts which is close to what you are measuring (4.58 volts) That means each LED has 7.5 - 4.62 = 2.88 volts. That in turn, means you would need a voltage source of at least 5 times that (14.4 volts) to be able to turn them on when connected in series. You only had 9.28 volts so they did not turn on and the current was 0.

Comment: Brilliant! I feel like we're so close to solving it.
To clarify : Why do all LED's in parallel have the ability to use 7.5V and those in series don't? In other words: Each LED has 2.88 and even then they work (in parallel mode). What makes the parallel mode able to distribute 5x2.88V?

Comment: @EagleEye123 It seems like you struggle with a very fundamental law of DC circuits (and it is indeed so fundamental that the answers don't even bother to mention it). Which is: Between parallel branches, voltage on each branch is the same, and current distributes between branches. While in a series, current is the same all along the series, but voltage devides up ("drops") between the different parts of the series (not necessarily equally). This fact is a simple result of conservation of charge and energy. Does this make sense to you and do the explanations get clearer now?

Comment: @Scrontch Thank you so much. Thanks for your comprehension, above all. It's hard to find help, especially when you don't know how to phrase the question.
That's exactly what I needed. Conservation of energy is the phrase what I was looking for and everything is clear now. Thanks again.